How to convert df to csv file using to_csv without quotation marks and messing with the content further?
I convert dfs to CSV file as folowing:
df_test.to_csv('path', sep=';', index=False, header=False)

The output rows in the file should be like this:

smiles;6

Instead:

"smiles;6"

Tried:
df_test.to_csv('path', sep=';', index=False, header=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

The error:

need to escape, but no escapechar set

Tried:
df_test.to_csv('path', sep=';', index=False, header=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar=';')

The output:

smiles;;6

Tried:
df_test.to_csv('path', sep=';', index=False, header=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='\0')

The output:

smiles[nul];6

where [nul] is some kind of symbol that cannot the copied and pasted
The df_test dataframe after convertion looks like this:

"[F-].CCCCN+(CCCC)CCCC.CC(C)(C)Si(C)[O:24][CH2:25]C@@H:26[O:28][CH2:29]C@@H:30[O:42][c:43]1[c:44]2c:45n:49[n:50][cH:51]2>C1CCOC1>[OH:24][CH2:25]C@@H:26[O:28][CH2:29]C@@H:30[O:42][c:43]1[c:44]2c:45n:49[n:50][cH:51]2;6"


"Cl[c:2]1[c:3]2c:4[nH:8]c:9[cH:10]2.[NH:20]1[CH2:21][CH2:22][c:23]2[cH:24][cH:25][cH:26][cH:27][c:28]21>CCCCO>[c:2]1([N:20]2[CH2:21][CH2:22][c:23]3[cH:24][cH:25][cH:26][cH:27][c:28]32)[c:3]2c:4[nH:8]c:9[cH:10]2;1"


"[NH2:1][c:2]1[c:3]2n:4c:8[n:9][c:10]2-[c:11]1[cH:12][cH:13]c:14[cH:24][cH:25]1>CCCC#CC(=O)O>[NH2:1][c:2]1[c:3]2n:4c:8[n:9][c:10]2-[c:11]1[cH:12][cH:13]c:14[cH:24][cH:25]1;2"


"Br[c:2]1[cH:3]c:4c:5[cH:6][cH:7]1.Cc1ccccc1P(c1ccccc1C)c1ccccc1C.CCN(CC)CC.C:56(=[O:59])[O:60][CH3:61]>CC(=O)[O-].[Pd+2].CC(=O)[O-].O.CN(C)C=O>[c:2]1(/[CH:58]=[CH:57]/C:56[O:60][CH3:61])[cH:3]c:4c:5[cH:6][cH:7]1;3"


"Br[c:22]1[cH:21][n:20]c:19[cH:24][cH:23]1.CCNCC.[CH:36]1([C:39]#[CH:40])[CH2:37][CH2:38]1.Cc1ccccc1>CN(C)C=O.[Pd+4].c1ccc(P-c2ccccc2)cc1.c1ccc(P-c2ccccc2)cc1.c1ccc(P-c2ccccc2)cc1.c1ccc(P-c2ccccc2)cc1.[Cu+].[I-]>[NH2:1][C:2]1=[N:7]C@:6([c:10]2[cH:11]c:12[cH:13][cH:14][c:15]2[F:16])[CH2:5]C@@H:4[O:3]1;3"

All the rows are separated.

maybe you have wrong data in dataframe. Maybe you have string smiles;6 in some cell - so it has to add quotation to keep it correctly. Better check what you have in DataFrame. Maybe you read it incorrectly or you put all in one column. And this need to split it before you write in file.

Please post a complete example that demonstrates the problem, including the actual full contents of the dataframe.  As it is, we're just guessing at the contents of your df_test.

@ furas all elements are "object" type

You could try using sep="," - based on the error message you include it appears using ";" is ambiguous without allowing to_csv to quote

I tried sep=',' and it worked as expected

FYI sep=',' is the default so you don't even need to specify it.

Use empty quotes as the escapechar.
df_test.to_csv('path', sep=';', index=False, header=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='')

this will work

It didn't work, the error occured

what python version do you use it worked perfectly for me what error occured
